# YouTube intent on Android TV

Tags: youtube, android-tv

Is there a way to launch the YouTube app in Android TV with an intent? Is is possible to pass a keyword to search for? It doesn't seem to mention something related to Android TV developer site.

Comment: Which library you are using to develop your tv app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question, yes, it is possible using [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

For second question, you may use `createSearchIntent` mentioned in [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#Summary)

You can also refer related question, [Use Youtube API in Android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184556/use-youtube-api-in-android-tv)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [YouTubeIntents documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#Overview), there are public methods which can be used like `canResolvePlayVideoIntent()` to check if the YouTube application installed on the user's device supports the play video intent. Required parameters and returned results for different methods can be seen in the documentation.