# Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer

Tags: android-youtube-api

When I try to play a youtube video on android using the youtube official api I get this error in logcat

> E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.

and then the `onError` callback is triggered with `NOT_PLAYABLE` reason.

Is it something configured incorrectly for the video?

This is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw6Mg81YMg0

Comment: you can try this alternative YouTube player to see if it gives the same error: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

Comment: In my case this error in logcat appears for each video but it still works ok, it's being played without any errors or crashes. I guess we can just ignore it

Answer (score 1):

had same problem when I created my project for Android TV as the target device, then I create a new project for phone and tablet. Now it works

hope this helps.

Comment: Check this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184556/use-youtube-api-in-android-tv)